# can't insert mmddyy10. format proc sql

Tags: sql, date, sas, sql-insert

I have a table with column as_of_date that is formatted as MMDDYY10. in SAS 7.1

```
proc sql;  
    INSERT INTO mytable (as_of_date)  
    VALUES (12/31/2016);  
run;
```

and I get the following error:
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, ), +, ',', -, MISSING, NULL, USER.

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Note: if I change the value to 12/31/16 it still does not work. If I put quotes around it ('12/31/2016') I get the error:
ERROR: Value 1 of VALUES clause 1 does not match the data type of the corresponding column in the object-item list (in the SELECT 
       clause).

If I insert it without slashes (12312016) it is inserted without errors as ********

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the DDMMMYYYY format within quotes and the `d` modifier:

```
proc sql noprint;  
    INSERT INTO mytable (as_of_date)  
    VALUES ("31dec2016"d);  
quit;
```

Another way to look at it is SAS is looking for the numeric value underneath a date format. You can check the actual value and use the following code to get the same result:

```
data check;
    date = "31dec2016"d;
run;

proc sql noprint;  
    INSERT INTO mytable (as_of_date)  
    VALUES (20819);  
quit;
```